# Finding a proof of the intermediate value theorem in arbitrary dimensions

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I know that the following variation of the intermediate value theorem in $n$ dimensions is true using some results from degree theory:

Let $g\colon \mathbb{D}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous map such that $g(x)+tx\ne 0$ for all $x\in\partial\mathbb{D}^n$ and $t\ge 0.$ There exists an $x$ such that $g(x)=0$

The proof using degree theory goes as follows. The map $h(x,t)=tg(x)+(1-t)x$ is a homotopy between the identity map on $\mathbb{D}^n$ and $g$ such that $h(x,t)$ does not vanish for any $x\in\partial\mathbb{D}^n$ or $t\in[0,1].$ The homotopy invariance of degree therefore implies that $g$ has a zero on $\mathbb{D}^n$ since the identity has a zero on $\mathbb{D}^n.$

I was interested to know if there was some proof out there of this theorem that did not use degree theory and instead used more elementary techniques. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.